# sqlite alleged corruption - filename specific

Tags: sqlite

I have an sqlite file, that when checked (and used), causes errors.  Canonical example:

```
$ sqlite db.sqlite pragma\ integrity_check |& head -n 2
*** in database main ***
Page 29255: btreeInitPage() returns error code 11
```

However, if I copy this to a second DB, and check that ... no issues!

```
$ cp -v db.sqlite db.2.sqlite
'db.sqlite' -> 'db.2.sqlite'

$ md5sum db.sqlite db.2.sqlite
8381026d6e4817023bfdb7c5a9a25b6c  db.sqlite
8381026d6e4817023bfdb7c5a9a25b6c  db.2.sqlite

$ sqlite db.2.sqlite pragma\ integrity_check
ok
```

1. Since this is in the same directory, it's on the same filesystem, which has >3G free.
2. The files are 105M in size.
3. Prefixing with `pragma temp_store=2` makes no appreciable difference (I have ~50% free of 32G ram; no swap in use)
4. Since I can copy the file and use the copy successfully, it surely can't be a file-level issue.
5. lsof reports nothing else using the file; I have rebooted to make double-sure.  The file has a single name (nlink==1), so I don't believe it can be used under any other name.
6. I had suspected a disk issue, but nothing is being reported in dmesg or via journalctl; and if it were, surely the cp would fail and/or not give me a working file?
7. Copying the file back from `db.2.sqlite` to `db.sqlite` makes no difference.
8. If I copy `db.sqlite` to a different filesystem, and symlink to that: I still see the integrity_check violation if I look at the symlink; but not if I look at the copied file on the other filesystem.
9. If I copy `db.sqlite` to `db.3.sqlite`; and hard-link the two: `db.3.sqlite` checks fine, but `db.sqlite` fails as above.
10. Writing this, I discovered that if I:

    1. Copy `db.sqlite` to `db.3.sqlite` (in the same directory)
    2. `ln -sfn db.3.sqlite db.sqlite`
    3. Integrity check `db.sqlite`: that works! `db.sqlite` now checks fine.
    4. Use `db.sqlite`; make some changes (that previously were failing, leading to the integrity check)
    5. `db.sqlite`/`db.3.sqlite` have now changed, and both still check fine.
    6. Remove `db.sqlite`, and `cp db.3.sqlite db.sqlite`
    7. `db.sqlite` now fails checks again.

So I have a nasty workaround... but exactly what is going on here is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved: in the same directory, there are additional files - `db.sqlite-shm` and `db.sqlite-wal`.  I guess the latter was corrupt (probably during a disk full event): moving it out of the way, everything starts working normally.